# Liquid disappearing in Mantaflow when container is animated

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking, mantaflow

I am using Blender 2.92 os OS 11

I have done okay with Mantaflow and it works once I understand what I believe to  be quirks...

I am doing my first animation where I am moving the container/collision object (a pitcher).  When moving the water disappears.

The video of this is: [Leaky Pitcher](https://cjbpmp.com/movies/leakynosound.mov)

Note:  I also made the liquid a child of the pitcher, thinking that it needed to move, but it did not work.  The liquid stayed a gloomy mess like in the first frame.  Liquid and mesh is baked.

Blender File: [image]

Additional Screenshots with some settings:

[image: Start of animation]
[image: Middle- where'd it go?]
[image: Did it evaporate?]

Comment: Can U add screenshots?

Comment: Hmm, I added a link to a video, and the blender file.  I thought that would be enough, but I can add some screenshots.  Is there anything you would like to see?

Comment: Well, the 3D viewport just before and after the disappearance, and maybe the fluid domain settings. PS: avoid video links when possible as a few spammers have done really nasty things by posting video links .

Comment: Okay, just an update.  I changed the timescale max and min to 10 and 8 respectively, and it took a lot loooooonger to render... but exactly the same problem.

Comment: OK, thanks for the screenshots. Huh, yeah, it looks like the simulation is leaking fluid. I’m not sure why, though. I haven’t experimented with FLIP much.

Comment: if you are leaking fluid the 2 main reasons are: resolution too low and thickness not high enough.

Comment: So I pushed the resolution to 128 and increased the thickness of the effector to 1.2.  Same result.  

I switched from FLIP to APIC, and there was no difference.

Finally, instead of making the liquid a child of the pitcher, I moved it independently, and there was no difference.  The water is not leaking out, per se, since it is not going anywhere.  It just disappears.

Comment: you are right, i also tried different things - but found no solution. Maybe - i didn't try that - Flip Fluid would do it better....